# Excel Services PowerPivot - Item Level Permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, powerpivot

I have implemented PowerPivot Chart, PowerView and uploaded the same to PowerPivot gallery on BI Site. Excel Services is configured with "Unattended Service Account" to retrive data from Data Source. Currently, I have populated the PowerPivot Data Model based on both SharePoint list and MS SQL Server.

Both SharePoint list and SQL Server has item level/row level permissions set, i.e. the records/data is shown based on current logged-in user's access.

Since I am using Unattended Service Account, I am facing no problem to Show/Filter/Drill down data as the Unattended Service Account has enough privileges to query all data from SQL Server/SharePoint list.

The only way I can think of securing, is to set appropriate access at PowerPivot Gallery library in BI site, appropriate access to SharePoint list/SQL database.

I would like to know whether it is possible to implement item level/row level permissions such that when PowerPivot/PowerView is opened, the data is displayed based on user's access instead of service account.

Another question I have is related to SilverLight. Since PowerView runs on SilverLight and SilverLight going to be deprecated in 2021 ([Link](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html)), is it still advisable to develop PowerView dashboards in SharePoint.